# Running stereo_match.cpp of OpenCV_Sample

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, stereo-3d, opencv3.1

I have 'stereo_match' through the g++ compiler.

My environment is :

- Ubuntu 15.1 Of VirtualBox
- OpenCV 3.1.0

I don't know the running command. I tried :

```
./stereo_match --left left12.jpg --right right12.jpg --method BM --ndisp 32.
```

But it failed with error :

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (undeclared position 0 requested) in
>   getByIndex, file
>   /home/usera/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/command_line_parser.cpp line
>   169
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>   what():
>   /home/usera/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/command_line_parser.cpp:169:
>   error: (-5) undeclared position 0 requested in function getByIndex
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: This seems to be a bug in `cv::CommandLineParser` -- I just hard coded my input file names in the source (yuck) -- I don't have time to chase the bug down for now.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a wrong parser key string. It is missing the positional arguments for the two filenames (the most important parameters!)

In "stereomatch.cpp", instead of:

```
cv::CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv,
    "{help h||}{algorithm||}{max-disparity|0|}{blocksize|0|}{no-display||}{scale|1|}{i||}{e||}{o||}{p||}");
```

it should read:

```
cv::CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv,
    "{@image1||} {@image2||} {help h||}{algorithm||}{max-disparity|0|}{blocksize|0|}{no-display||}{scale|1|}{i||}{e||}{o||}{p||}");
```

trivial error, maybe a leftover from a previous version.